# MosFet Design Help

Tags: mosfet, pcb, pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad

I posted yesterday about wondering what diode an SMD component on my board was. Here I am again, wondering if this schematic and PCB design looks reasonable. I looked at my original in hand component from a few years back I bought, however I wanted to recreate it. I am only in second year of Electrical Technology program and this is my first time using a software such as Eagle as we aren't taught this. This is used in an Airsoft Gun to protect the contacts. I am not 100% sure how the original is wired or how it works, but I have some understanding. The only hard part was finding where the 2200 SMD Resistor was wired to, and where it is on the schematic is where my meter's continuity showed there was continuity so I went by that hoping it would function. Thoughts?

Info: The hole that connects to the fuse is where the signal wire mounts, to go to the contacts. The two holes connecting the Drain and the Sources, with TVS Diode underneath, are where the negative terminal connects back to the battery connector.

Thanks so much folks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Embiggen your schematic and board view!  No need to make everyone zoom and squint!

Comment: Sorry, figured eagle would’ve done this on their own.

Comment: Please ask a specific question so it can be answered.